# Rearrange JSON data to appear in a table row

Tags: json, angular, typescript

In a table I want to display the following items in a single Row. Can someone help me out loop the JSON so I can rearrange the items as shown below.

> StudentId | CourseTitle | TextbookName
>
> 23 | Biology | Biology Today

**JSON**

```
{
    "studentId": 23,
    "course": [{
        "courseTitle": "Biology",
        "textBook": 1,
        "TextBooks": {
            "textbookId": 1,
            "textbookName": "Biology Today"
        }
    }, ... ]
}
```

**CODE**

```
<table class="table">
     <tbody>
         <tr *ngFor="let student of this.listOfStudents">
             <td >{{student ?.studentId}}</td>                                   
         </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you please provide more info what you want exactly do? I can see there is an array of courses so how do you want to display them?

Comment: In the following format as stated in the post. 'StudentId | CourseTitle | TextbookName'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right, try following:

```
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let student of this.listOfStudents">
        <tr *ngFor="let course of student.course">
            <td>{{ student.studentId }} | {{ course.courseTitle }} | {{ course.TextBooks.textbookName }}</td>                                   
        </tr>
    </ng-container>
 </tbody>
</table>
```